# AS3: object declared within function, listener within object...do they both get GC?

Tags: actionscript-3, object, garbage-collection, flashdevelop, event-listener

Evening y'all,

I normally have no need to ask as there is a plethora of info, but this I cannot find -at least, not specifically.

Here's the gist: I'm declaring an object inside a function, then slapping a listener within that object. Question: once the function has run, does both the object AND the function get trashed?? I DO NOT want random listeners without objects hanging around, for obvious reasons.

In case it helps, here be the code simplified:

(feel free to make it look more presentable, apologies about that)

`public function textSfx(chPos:int, otlPos:int):void
{`

```
        var sfxTimer:Timer = new Timer (300, 6);


            sfxTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, textSfxHandler(chPos));


        sfxTimer.start();
    }

    public function textSfxHandler(chPos:int):Function
    {
        return function(evt:TimerEvent):void
        {
            trace("char being affected is: " + chPos);
        }
    }
```

It's working absolutely fine, but I worry about the listeners laying about without a home. Surely that's not the case, right? RIGHT??

P.S. the object is declared inside the function due to multiple elements requiring simultaneous timers, which didn't work with a singular, outside declared timer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**In space, no one can hear you scream**
And that's what you have here. You have a Timer that nobody knows about, and you have a callback that only the Timer knows about. So, instead of tethering your astronaut (Timer) to your spaceship and your screwdriver to him you've tethered the two of them together and let them drift off where the garbage collector can scoop them up at any moment, whether the Timer has fired and the callback has run or not.

What you need to do is add *some* kind of a reference to hold on to your Timer, or you have no guarantee it will ever fire/trigger the callback. You're probably just as well to declare a variable to hold that timer (note that then you'll want to pass that in when your closure is created).  If you choose to use a Dictionary, you want to *not* use weak keys, or else you're just tethering your astronaut to a screwdriver on one side and a wrench on the other.

This means that you *do* need to null the variable containing the timer and stop the timer (since you can't remove the event listener if you use an anonymous function) when you are no longer using the instance that created the Timer.

For more on how these things work, check out [this blog post](http://www.developria.com/2010/12/functional-actionscript-part-1.html).

Comment: That's pretty much what I thought, many thanks! The callback seems to work no probs, so my main concern was the GC, and thanks to your splendid metaphor I see that it does work :D although imo GC should of been linked to some gravitational phenomena such as a black hole, but otherwise impeccable ;)

Comment: Amy, I don't think anonymous functions in AS3 get GC'ed. I tried it here: http://wonderfl.net/c/yeF0 and although I agree that it depends on the GC getting fired with the hack (which I'm pretty sure still works). I guess if you profile this application, the profiler would also show similar information.

Comment: Anonymous functions get collected, or not, depending on a number of factors. If the object that they are added to as event listeners is still in memnory, they will not be GC'ed (unless you remove them with arguments.callee).

Comment: Keep in mind that GC will only run if it needs to, so in a small example like yours you won't see it happen. Try creating and removing (completely dereferencing) several hundred large Bitmaps and then see what happens.

Comment: Okay added memory eating code which is cleared later with system.mem stats too. The GC is definitely hitting. The timers still keep working.

Comment: You're holding on to the BitmapDatas in the vector, so there's nothing going on that would force the GC to run.

Comment: No, I'm null-ing the vector after 2 seconds... as is apparent in the drop in memory usage too

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28914/discussion-between-catholicon-and-amy-blankenship)

Answer (score 0):

Timer object and anonymus function will remain in memory until Timer is linked to an event listener. Your code will not let GC to do its job.

You may use weak reference parameter when adding listener (5th parameter):

```
sfxTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, textSfxHandler(chPos), false,0,true);
```

but it is a bad practice to use anonymous functions anyway

Will the following code do well in your case? Note that I use named listeners and not recreating them each time:

```
    private var timerPool:Dictionary = new Dictionary();
    public function textSfx(chPos:int, otlPos:int=0):void {
        var sfxTimer:Timer = new Timer (300, 6);
        timerPool[sfxTimer] = chPos;
        sfxTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, textSfxHandler);
        sfxTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE, textSfxComplete);
        sfxTimer.start();

    }
    public function textSfxHandler(e:TimerEvent):void
    {
        var sfxTimer:Timer = e.target as Timer;
        trace("char being affected is" + timerPool[sfxTimer]);
    }
    public function textSfxComplete(e:TimerEvent):void {
        var sfxTimer:Timer = e.target as Timer;
        sfxTimer.removeEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, textSfxHandler);
        sfxTimer.removeEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE, textSfxComplete);
        delete timerPool[sfxTimer];
    }
```

Comment: You have this pretty much backward. The timer has a reference to the function, not the function to the timer. So since nobody knows about the Timer in the original code, the GC will be able to collect both. Anonymous functions are only bad practice if you don't understand what you are doing with them (which most people don't). They can actually be good practice in some instances where you want to limit the scope of how much information the object you're adding a listener to has access to.